# Highcharts: 2nd x axis, first and last labels cut off

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart with 2 linked x axes, mostly duplicated - one on top, one on bottom.

They use categories, and in order to trim extra space off of the left and right of the chart, I have set the min to 0.25, and max to [# of categories].75.

The first x axis responds as desired, and shows all categories correctly.

The 2nd x axis does not show the first or the last category.

If I remove the min/max settings, both axes show correctly, but with more space than I want.

But since the first axis does show all categories, it must be possible for both axes to show all categories.

Axis code:

```
xAxis  : [{
    min:0.25,
    max:5.75,
    opposite: true,
    categories: catsTop,
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
},{
    linkedTo:0,
    categories: catsBot,
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on'
}]
```

`tickmarkPlacement: 'on'` is required for this chart.

Fiddle:

- https://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/mvgymfw6/7/

I have tried changing the chart `alignTicks` property, `showFirstLabel`/`showLastLabel`, `startOnTick`/`endOnTick`, have placed first axis on top/2nd axis on bottom, first axis on bottom/second axis on top, etc, but can't get the 2nd axis to properly show the labels.

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: It's caused by extremes, which won't be rendered for linked axis, since those aren't within the range (simply 0 < 0.25 and 6 > 5.75). I'm not sure if this we can call it a bug. However, you can workaround this by using separate axis (not linked), with `showEmpty` set to true and one series (empty) connected to that axis. See demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mvgymfw6/11/ . Of course, there is another solution: don't use categorized axis, but linear, with `formatter` and `tickInterval: 1`.

Comment: Interesting. So, pull in the category names through the formatter, you mean? I will try out both options and see what works best.

Comment: Ok, skipping the categories and using the formatter to pull in the label values works for me, especially since I was already building the categories as an array outside of the chart. Thanks for the explanation and advice.  Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/mvgymfw6/embedded/result/